# Intermittent java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03120: two-taskconversion routine: integer overflow exception

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I get the following error intermittently when my spring app starts up. I am using oracle with dbcp pooling as my datasource bean in spring.

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Errorpreloading the connection pool
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1238)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
            ... 46 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03120: two-taskconversion routine: integer overflow
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:204)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:406)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:799)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:368)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
            at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1059)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1235)
            ... 49 more
```

Comment: We got the same problem with Oracle 11g on a Windows Server. Many days it does not occur; some days it occurs 5 times within a couple of minutes. We have no clue what causes this problem.

Comment: Seems to me that this is some driver network data overflow issue. Happens only when windows machine is connected to linux. When I run same code on linux it works just fine all the time. One option could be use wireshark and see what is sent differently over the network when this error occurs, but I never got around to doing that.